# JavaCV: the best way to insert bit mask to color image

Tags: opencv, javacv

I have a binary mask, created by opencv (8-bit opencv_core.Mat from org.bytedeco.javacpp, 0 for background, 255 for objects), and some other matrix "source", color or grayscale, any depth (8-bit, 16-bit, float...)

I need to "draw" the mask on the source matrix by white color: pixels 255 from the mask must become "white" on the source matrix.

What is the simplest way to do this IN JAVA?

I do the following:

```
    if (source.depth() != opencv_core.CV_8U) {
        mask.convertTo(mask, source.depth(), OTools.maxPossibleValue(source) / 255.0, 0.0);
    }
    if (source.channels() > 1) {
        opencv_imgproc.cvtColor(mask, mask, opencv_imgproc.CV_GRAY2BGR, source.channels());
    }
    opencv_core.bitwise_or(source, mask, mask);
```

(maxPossibleValue returns 255 for CV_8U, 65535 for CV_16U, 1.0 for floating-point). But I hope, there is more obvious and universal way. For example, what will be if source is not BGR, but BGRA or other color model?

Comment: Matrices in OpenCV are just two dimensional arrays of one dimensional arrays and no more. The only thing that you have to check is the datatype of this array and the number of channels no matter it is HSV or BGR etc. Does the color space affect your code?

Comment: I understand this. So, it seems strange to use cvtColor to increase the number of channels.
In C++, we can use overloaded version with scalar, where mask is the 3rd argument (really mask, not an ordinary matrix argument). In Java I didn't find way to do this simply.